# Subview Not Removing after Several "Remove View" Methods

Tags: swift, view, uiactivityindicatorview

I have this nice function that adds an activity indicator view, with a regular view behind it. When I add it, it adds fine. The problem is, when I try to remove it, nothing happens. I've tried:
`.removeFromSuperview`,
`.isHidden = true` and putting these methods in the main queue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                alertView.alpha = 0
                alertView.removeFromSuperview()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
            alertView.isHidden = true
            activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
```

I don't know what other methods to try...It seems all the other questions like this have one of the methods that I have as a solution. The function uses a boolean to determine whether or not to stop the activityIndicator. Here is my code:

```
static func showLoadingView(inViewController: UIViewController, turning: Bool){

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        let alertView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: activityIndicator.frame.origin.x, y: activityIndicator.frame.origin.y , width: 35, height: 35))
        if(turning){
        alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230, alpha: 0.8)
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        activityIndicator.center = alertView.center
        inViewController.view.addSubview(alertView)
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        alertView.alpha = 0
        activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        alertView.center = inViewController.view.center

        alertView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        alertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            alertView.alpha = 1
            alertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
        }
        ///////
        else {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                alertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y:1.3)
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                alertView.alpha = 0
                alertView.removeFromSuperview()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
            alertView.isHidden = true
            activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
            print("Done")

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared **alertView** which is out of scope when you called false.As a result, your call could not identify the alertView instance.

You can solve this issue in tow ways:

1. Declare your **alertView**  outside of the function as a static.

   ```
   static let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
   static let alertView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: activityIndicator.frame.origin.x, y: activityIndicator.frame.origin.y , width: 35, height: 35))
   static func showLoadingView(inViewController: UIViewController, turning: Bool){}
   ```
2. In false case: find the **subview** using **restorationIdentifier** and remove.

   ```
   static func showLoadingView(inViewController: UIViewController, turning: Bool){
   if(turning){
       let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
      let alertView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: activityIndicator.frame.origin.x, y: activityIndicator.frame.origin.y , width: 35, height: 35))
       alertView.restorationIdentifier = "myalert"

       alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230, alpha: 0.8)
       alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
       activityIndicator.center = alertView.center
       inViewController.view.addSubview(alertView)
       activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
       activityIndicator.startAnimating()
       alertView.alpha = 0
       activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
       alertView.center = inViewController.view.center

       alertView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
       alertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
           alertView.alpha = 1
           alertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
       }
   }
       ///////
   else {
       for view in inViewController.view.subviews {
           if (view.restorationIdentifier == "myalert") {
               print("I FIND IT");
               (view as! UIView).removeFromSuperview();
           }
       } 
    }
   }
   ```